# C++ Sqlite3 code seems to have issues prepping a statement

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement

I was trying to just query some input to make sure things were inserted correctly.

I was doing the following:

```
//open database into 'db'
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
string query = "select * from A;";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, 0)==SQLITE_OK){
  //...
}else{
  cout << "Error prepping statement" << endl;
}
```

I was following a demo from dreamincode:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/  I just have no idea what i was doing wrong.   Am i using the wrong prepare method, or defining something wrong?

**Edit:**  The Returned Error Code is 1:  SQL error or missing database.  Am i doing the SQL statement wrong?  I triple checked to make sure the DB was indeed open

**Edit: RESOLVED**  I downloaded the database, opened it with a sqlite3 reader... and noticed something i SHOULDve been told about.  The schema changed without me knowing without documentation being sent to the entire dev team.  I am sending a very nice email to my coworker about that

Comment: Is there copy-paste bug:  `-1 &statement`. Should it be `-1, &statement` ?

Comment: Please show how you open the database file; and use [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get a better error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema was changed without documentation or telling anyone on the dev team.  I had to dl the db and open it with an sqlite3 reader.

Im going to have words with him about this.